# Uplink-less Bridge with systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, arch-linux, virtual-machine, bridge, systemd-networkd

I am trying to configure several Linux bridges, all without physical uplinks, for use as isolated virtual networks with KVM/QEMU. I am running Archlinux, which uses systemd-networkd to configure network interfaces. I am deploying the machine using Cloud-Init. Aside form the issue of Cloud-Init not generating the correct files (more about that in a separate question), I have found that maybe systemd-networkd will not bring an bridge interface online unless some form of uplink port is configured.

If I have only two files, the netdev file and the network file, the bridge interface is created but does not get configured with the ip address and brought online:

```
</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-br0.netdev>

[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge



</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-br0.network>

[Address]
Address=192.168.231.29/23

[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=192.168.230.5

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0

Gateway=192.168.230.4
```

The end result of just these two files is a long boot delay along with:

```
#> ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:e7:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s2
    altname ens2
3: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:02:bb:df:fc:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If I create an additional file that allocates a physical uplink:

```
</etc/systemd/network/10-cloud-init-eth0.network>

[Match]
MACAddress=00:16:3e:00:e7:1d
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

All is right in the world:

```
#> ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:e7:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s2
    altname ens2
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:02:bb:df:fc:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.231.29/23 brd 192.168.231.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9802:bbff:fedf:fc5a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On Debain, which uses IfUpDown to configure interfaces, I have to designate NONE (I think) for the switchports of a bridge in order for the bridge to come online. I can't seem to find any documentation for systemd.networkd that defines how to configure a bridge with no uplinks. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes` in the [Network] section of your bridge network file. (cf. [Network section options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html))

A bridge without a slave device is in the `NO-CARRIER` state and `systemd-networkd` leaves interfaces that are in the `NO-CARRIER` state unconfigured by default.